# Unbind the click event after sorting is done

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list of images, which are made sortable by jquery sortable. I can drag and drop the images for sorting purpose. 
Now, Parent anchor of every image also has Click event of light box event attached.

So, When user clicks the image, it gets opened in the lightbox. And I can also drag and drop image at other place.

Event Bubbling: 
When I try to drag the image, click event is getting triggered. Which I don't expect. How shall I disable the click event while dragging the image ?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="shop-photos">
<div id="shop-photos">
<ul class="ui-sortable">

    <li class="photo-frame media-placeholder media-9108" id="mediaid-9108">
    <a class="preload" data-media-id="9108" href="http://usauto.vo.llnwd.net/o37/dev/07/95/0795f614c4e4d7704e54cc6e48d7ce2c0c16c91b13566015990874.jpg"><img id="9108" data-media-id="9108" src="/shop_portal/api_get_uploaded_photo/?mediaid=9108"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="photo-frame media-placeholder media-9082" id="mediaid-9082">
    <a class="preload" data-media-id="9082" href="http://usauto.vo.llnwd.net/o37/dev/4d/f5/4df5db9819ff891deb60e9c5d85315ccbed41d9413565853192746.jpg"><img id="9082" data-media-id="9082" src="/shop_portal/api_get_uploaded_photo/?mediaid=9082"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="photo-frame media-placeholder media-9089" id="mediaid-9089">
    <a class="preload" data-media-id="9089" href="http://usauto.vo.llnwd.net/o37/dev/9b/24/9b248b3c1308cf3f57f4220ec2aea2c0e954592113565988843784.jpg"><img id="9089" data-media-id="9089" src="/shop_portal/api_get_uploaded_photo/?mediaid=9089"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="photo-frame media-placeholder media-9391" id="mediaid-9391">
    <a class="preload" data-media-id="9391" href="http://usauto.vo.llnwd.net/o37/dev/69/ed/69ed3eac6bfd4af09256e54ed3e5d2d4d4f9948a13572811600895.jpg"><img id="9391" data-media-id="9391" src="/shop_portal/api_get_uploaded_photo/?mediaid=9391"></a>
    </li>

</ul> 
</div>
</div>
```

I did this with below code.

```
$('#shop-photos a').lightBox({overlayBgColor: '#111', overlayOpacity: 0.6, containerResizeSpeed: 150});

     $("#shop-photos ul").sortable({
             start: function(event, ui) {
              ui.item.find("a").unbind("click");
             },
             stop: function(event, ui) {            
               $("#shop-photos a").bind("click");
               },
             opacity: 0.6, 
             cursor: 'move', 
             update: function() {           
                var order = $(this).sortable("serialize"); 
                var arr_mediaid = order.split('&');
                for(var i=0;i<arr_mediaid.length;i++){
                    arr_mediaid[i] = arr_mediaid[i].replace("mediaid[]=", ""); 
                }
                $("input[id=sorted-photos]").val(arr_mediaid);
            }   
        })
```

I have removed the click event on the anchors properly. but, unable to bring is back after image dragging is done.

My Question is After sorting couple of times, the click event is not appearing back. Is the unbind event triggered properly? Have I unbinded it back at proper place ?

Comment: Does it stop working after a specific number of clicks, or randomly it stops working ?

Comment: @MandeepJain, +1. After sorting, click event of anchor is still disabled. So, if I click the image/anchor, ightbox doesn't appear, but Image gets opened in browser. (Answer: Only the image that I have dragged.)

Comment: It means lightbox internally binds its functions to the click events, and since you unbind it, lightbox functions get unbinded as well.
Try initializing your lightbox again in the stop function after you bind click

Comment: in click function Do u have any functionality?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a latest version of jQuery means u have to use `.on` and `.off`
bind is deprecated.

instead of unbind

```
ui.item.find("a").off("click");
```

instead of bind

```
$("#shop-photos a").on("click");
```

or if you want to disable the click event on a tag means

```
$("#shop-photos a").click(function() { return false; });
```

Answer (score 1):

the .bind() method takes two variables.  The event, "click" and a function.  You can't just say $("#shop-photos a").bind('click');

You need to say $("#shop-photos a").bind('click',[some function]);  That [some function] would be the lightbox trigger.

I would suggest using a separate icon for dragging, outside of the image thumbnail; separate your UI - one for dragging, one for zooming.

Otherwise, rebind the lightbox open function to the anchor after the drag is complete.  Make sense?